# Record my screen when my Selenium test is going on

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a test with Selenium and JAVA, I need to record my screen while the test is going on, I searched and found some tools such as [java-screen-recorder](https://code.google.com/p/java-screen-recorder/downloads/detail?name=java-screen-recorder-0.8.zip&can=2&q=) but it is not what I exactly need, what I need is a framework that I can add it to my program and call its function to start the screen record when my test starts and close and  save the record when my test is done.

Comment: saucelabs or browserstacks??

Comment: @Madhan sorry I have no idea what you are talking about ?

Comment: You can go for either of those .They'll record the webdriver and create a video for you.Just google those

Comment: @Madhan thanks, but anythings for free? I figured out that i need to but them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -  [Monte Media Library](http://www.randelshofer.ch/monte/). It is explained in "Selenium Testing Tools Cookbook", also look at Umesh's blogpost [Recording Screencast of Selenium Tests](http://unmesh.me/2012/01/13/recording-screencast-of-selenium-tests-in-java/)