# How to make Monte Media Library record multiple monitors?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, video-recording

I am using Selenium and JAVA to write a test, after a while I decided to [record my screen while the test is going on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948718/record-my-screen-when-my-selenium-test-is-going-on)  so I added [Monte](http://www.randelshofer.ch/monte/) framework to my program and it is working like a charm.
But at work I have two monitors and need to record both of them,
and also I need to specify the path that I want this framework to save my record in.

Comment: Good idea, can I please ask how is your last sentence relevant to your question? "and also I need to specify the path that I want this framework to save my record in."

Comment: @Yu Zhang I have two issues 1) record my both monitors 2) at windows it saves the record at Libraries\Videos folder but I want it to be saved at my program folder (or any where else)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MonteRecorder extends ScreenRecorder implements VideoRecorder {
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MonteRecorder.class);

ScreenRecorder videoRecorder = null;
private String name = null;

/**
 * MonteRecorder provides video capture of test script run.
 * 
 * @param name
 *            video file root name, appended with date time stamp.
 * @param movieFolder
 *            output folder for the video file, the filename will be set
 *            when the video is started.
 * @param dim
 *            Capturing area for the video
 * @throws IOException
 *             thrown if video file cannot be written to the output-file
 * @throws AWTException
 *             thrown if an error with the capturing area occurs
 */
public MonteRecorder(String name, File movieFolder)
    throws IOException, AWTException {

super(
    /* default config */
    GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
        .getDefaultScreenDevice()
        .getDefaultConfiguration(),
    /* Screen dimension for capture area */
    null,
    /* file format */
    new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.FILE, MimeTypeKey, MIME_AVI),
    /* output format for screen capture */
    new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
        CompressorNameKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
        DepthKey, 24, FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(15),
        QualityKey, 1.0f,
        KeyFrameIntervalKey, 15 * 60),
    /* output format for mouse capture */
    new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, "black",
        FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(30)),
    /* output format for audio - null == no audio */
    null,
    movieFolder);
this.name = name;
}
```

Add an additional parameter to the endof your arguments, there are several constructors in the lib, you need the one that accepts the movieFoler.
download [monte src jar](http://www.randelshofer.ch/monte/files/MonteMedia-0.7.7src-cc.zip)